# Find all real solutions for $7 x_{1}+4 x_{2}-13 x_{3}+x_{4}+6 x_{5}-x_{6}=30$

Tags: linear-algebra

This first think that comes to my mind is to get a leading pivot  (I'm not sure if I use the right terminology and if I use it correctly):

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc|c}{1} & {\frac{4}{7}} & {\frac{-13}{7}} & {\frac{1}{7}} & {\frac{6}{7}} & {\frac{-1}{7}} & {\frac{1}{7}} & {\frac{30}{7}}\end{array}\right]$$

But I do not know how to get a solution from this (Question 1). There are "too many" variables. I'm not sure how to specify the solution (Question 2).

Also, I think there are infinitely real solutions.

PS my linear algebra course have just started so I'm very novice. The only tool I have is the elimination algorithm.

Comment: Not only are there infinitely many solutions, but the dimension of the solution set in $\mathbb R^7$ is $6$.

Comment: There's nothing to eliminate since you have only one equation. If simply defines a hyperplane.

Comment: Okay. I just skimmed foreward in my textbook. I can see there is a way to specify the solution with a parameter form.

Comment: @Xenusi But the thing is, there are going to be $6$ parameters anyways so the equation will just be the same as the parameterization.

Comment: @Bernard OK. To eliminate means to make the coefficient of $x_1$ equal $0$, right?

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, I can see that.

Comment: I think I can solve this one by myself from this point.

Comment: It's not necessarily that. This depends on what you decide are  the main variables. It mainly is equivalent to row reduction, but with a single row which reduction can you hope?

Comment: @Bernard I got that. I was just asking what it means to eliminate a variable 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you already have is the equation of a hyperplane, which describes all solutions.

It may seem a bit lame, but we can parametrize it by simply rewriting it as:
$$x_{6} = 7 x_{1}+4 x_{2}-13 x_{3}+x_{4}+6 x_{5}-30$$
That is, we can freely pick all $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4},x_{5}$ and treat them as parameters. Then $x_6$ is given as function of those parameters.

If we want, we can write it more clearly as a parametrized expression:
\begin{cases}
x_1 = \lambda_1\\
x_2 = \lambda_2\\
x_3 = \lambda_3\\
x_4 = \lambda_4\\
x_5 = \lambda_5\\
x_6 = 7 \lambda_{1}+4 \lambda_{2}-13 \lambda_{3}+\lambda_{4}+6 \lambda_{5}-30
\end{cases}

Comment: @KlassvanAarsen
How do I know that the solution is real?

Comment: @Xenusi, if we fill in any point, we get a solution. For instance (0,0,0,0,0,-30) is a solution. Therefore the solution is real.

Comment: It could also be complex then? One could fill in $$x_{6}=7 \lambda_{1}+4 \lambda_{2}-13 \lambda_{3}+\lambda_{4}+6 \lambda_{5}-30$$ with complex numbers. I think it's important to write that the paramters should run over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If we want to find _real_ solutions, we need to fill in _real_ numbers.